# VB.NET Classes trouble

Tags: vb.net

I have a form that contains an object "TextBox1" (TextBox1 control)

In the code section I've initialized a new TextBox object that is not on the form like this:

```
  Dim aa As New TextBox
  aa = TextBox1 'THE CONTROL ON THE FORM
  aa.Text = "hi how are you?"
```

The TextBox1 on the form is now changed it wrote "hi how are you?"

shouldn't be the "aa" object and the "TextBox1" be separate one from another? means that changing one object wouldn't affect the other?

Why this happens?
And how to prevent this?

Means Separating the objects one from another.

Writing the code at this form

```
Public Sub blah(ByVal aa As TextBox)
    aa.Text = "hi how are you?"
End Sub
```

And then calling the sub by

```
    blah(TextBox1)
```

Doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: I think the bigger question is why do you need a hidden clone of TextBox1?  Why not just a string variable of the Text?

Comment: I need this in multithreading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.Net objects are passed by reference.
`aa` and `TextBox1` both refer to the same `TextBox` instance.

You can manually create a copy of an instance by copying over its properties to a different instance.

Comment: Yes I think so But how  I can do that You can manually create a copy of an instance by copying over its properties to a different instance.

Answer (score 0):

When you set an object equal to another, in this case `aa` to `TextBox1`, `aa` is now a pointer to `TextBox1` and any actions made to it will affect both.

A way to use it as just the value would be to use the instance in a function. As such.

```
Public Sub process(ByVal aa as Object)

'do stuff
End Sub
```

Comment: I Want to separate the objects one from another

Comment: Creating a separate function would allow you to pass it as a ByVal, which is not a pointer.

Comment: It shouldn't. Can you update the initial post? Also, why do you need to do this, not a very common practice.

Comment: @CamelSlack Despite the ByVal, a TextBox is an object: it will be passed ByRef.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no easy way to clone a TextBox but if you want to do this, you can just copy over the relevant properties:

```
Dim aa As New TextBox
aa.Text = TextBox1.Text
'Copy over other relevant properties here
aa.Text = "hi how are you?"
```

LarsTech raises a good question though. Do you really need to clone the whole textbox? Wouldn't it be sufficient to just copy over the text?

Also note that the code that you posted doesn't do what you think it does. By doing something like:

```
Dim aa As New TextBox
aa = TextBox1
```

You're first assigning the `aa` variable to a newly created textbox, then you're re-assigning this variable to the existing TextBox1. You've just lost your reference to the newly created textbox.